# What is Managed/Unmanaged Object in Realm DB?

Tags: android, realm

What is meant by the term `Managed Object` and `Unmanaged Object` in Realm DB ??
I have searched this term everywhere and I found these links [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-%E2%80%9Cmanaged-object%E2%80%9D-in-Java)
 & [managedObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/managedObject.html). But still unsure.

I know it's trivial but in Realm docs nowhere it is explained.

Comment: I don't think realm android has anything called managed and unmanaged object.

Comment: On their docs https://realm.io/docs/java/latest `Control+F` search for `managed` or `unmanaged` you will see in their code.

Comment: So what I was able to understand is a managed object is an object which is updated, when the data in DB changes. Suppose you fetch a result for a query and then you update the DB with the new data, so the results are also updated. However unmanaged data's values are not updated when data in the DB is updated.

Comment: I found this at Realm.io : ( it's quoting from a Swift doc, but the definition would be the same"... "Realm objects can be instantiated and used as unmanaged objects (i.e. not yet added to a Realm) just like regular Swift objects."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found some explanations in realm document.

[FAQ/What is the difference between a normal Java object and a Realm object?](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest#faq-pojo-vs-realmobject)

> Instances of Realm objects can be either managed or unmanaged.
>
> - Managed objects are persisted in Realm, are always up to date and thread confined. They are generally more lightweight than the unmanaged version as they take up less space on the Java heap.
> - Unmanaged objects are just like ordinary Java objects, they are not persisted and they will not be updated automatically. They can be moved freely across threads.

Comment: If unmanaged objects are not persisted then what will be the use of them ?? Because we are using Realm to store them in DB.

Comment: The purpose is that its thread safe. You need not get a new copy in new thread.

Comment: I am sorry but can you elaborate the thread concept ?? I mean how can there be multiple threads created ??